# How to add circle overlay to button when clicked?

Tags: android

I am attempting to add something like this to a button when clicked. However, the method is not recognized.

[image: example]

this is my attempt

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100,  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
    c.drawCircle(60,50,25, paint);

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_1:
            iv_court.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: *the method is not recognized* -- You should mention which method, because that would be a Java issue, not a problem with showing the circle

Comment: and you shouldn't draw onClick, rather on the onDraw